# How to fill in a shape with content in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, fill, clipping-mask

I am completely new to Illustrator, however my boss asked me to make a graphic in illustrator. A list of things he sent me:

First, this mock up image for what he wants:

[image]

as well as the .ai file for the filler information/icons, and the vector image for the lock shape.

I don't know how to put the 4 colored quadrants in to the lock image while isolating the center keyhole. Any suggestions? Feel free to be as basic and straightforward as possible. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing from your mockup that the keyhole isn't already part of the lock. If it is, ignore this first part.

Draw your keyhole using shapes and/or pen tool:

[image]

Use the Pathfinder panel to 'Unite' all the keyhole shapes. Then use 'Minus Front' with the lock and keyhole selected to cut out the keyhole. You should be left with one compound path.

[image]

Create your content, including a new background. Extend the edges of your background shapes over the edges of the lock. You can give your lock a stroke and no fill and keep it on top of your layer to use it as a guide.

[image]

Once you are finished, make sure your lock path is on top of everything else, select everything you want inside the lock and the lock itself and go to **Object → Clipping Mask → Make**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful, with the pictures for reference.